# How can I read dirty values in SQL UPDATE statement WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nolock

Let's assume I have the following query in two separate SSMS query windows:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE dbo.Jobs
SET [status] = 'Running'
OUTPUT Inserted.*
WHERE [status] = 'Waiting'
--I'm NOT committing yet
--Commit Transaction
```

I run query window 1 (but do not commit), and then I run query window 2.

I want for query window 2 to immediately update only rows that were inserted after I started query 1 (all new records come in with a status of 'Waiting'). However, SQL Server is waiting for the first query to finish, because in an update statement it's not reading dirty values (even if it's set to READ UNCOMMITTED);

Is there a way to overcome this?

In my application I will have 2 (or more) processes running it, I want that process 2 should be able to pickup the rows that process 1 have not picked up; I don't want that process 2 should need to wait until process 1 is finish

Comment: In my application I will have 2 (or more) processes running it, I want that process 2 should be able to pickup the rows that process 1 have not picked up;

I don't want that process 2 should need to wait until process 1 is finish

Comment: What is the cardinality of the status column, how many rows are likely to be at either status?

Comment: probably it will start with 50 in each status;

It will become more over time

Comment: I don't believe you want `read uncommitted` here, you just need to skip over rows already locked by a transaction, which you can do using `with(readpast)` hint

Comment: The solution is probably to get MORE strict, not less, and make sure each operation is as short-lived as possible. This may mean breaking up existing long-running jobs into smaller idempotent steps.

Comment: I suggest you do not try to use native locking for this. Instead I suggest you implement a proper mutex / queueing mechanism where a worker "reserves" one job and works on it. Any other worker can in parallel reserve and action their own work.

Answer (score 1):

**What you are asking for is simply impossible.**

Even at the lowest isolation level of `READ UNCOMMITTED` (aka `NOLOCK`), an `X-Lock` (exclusive) *must* be taken in order to make modifications. In other words, writes are always locked, even if the reads that fetched those rows were not locked.

So even though session 2 is running under `READ UNCOMMITTED` also, if it wants to do a modification it must also take an `X-Lock`, which is incompatible with the first X-Lock.

**The solution here is to either do this in one session, or commit immediately.** In any case, do not hold locks for any length of time, as it can cause massive blocking chains and even deadlocks.

If you want to just ignore all those rows which have been inserted, you could use the `WITH (READPAST)` hint.

---

**`READ UNCOMMITTED` as an isolation level or as a hint has huge issues.**

It can cause anything from deadlocks to completely incorrect results. For example, you could read a row twice, or not at all, when by the logical definition of the schema there should have been exactly one row. You could read entire pages twice or not at all.

You can get deadlocks due to `U-Lock`s not being taken in `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.

And you still take schema locks, so you can still get stuck behind a synchronous statistics update or an index rebuild.